# Multiple images sent to smtp server in a loop

Tags: python

For Raspberry Pi 3, I ran the following program, aiming to send a camera captured new image to a Gmail account, every 2 mins. However a problem occurred. In the first transmission, the captured image was sent. In the second transmission, both the first image and the newly taken image were sent. In the third transmission, three images were sent. I am new to Python. Could anybody provide some clues? Your help is much appreciated.

```
import smtplib
import time 
from email.mime.multipart  import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text  import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base  import MIMEBase 
from email.mime.image  import MIMEImage 
from email  import encoders 

from picamera  import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180

fromaddr = "jsmith05@yahoo.com.au"
toaddr = "jsmith05@gmail.com"

msg1 = MIMEMultipart()
msg1['From'] = fromaddr
msg1['To'] = toaddr
msg1['Subject'] = "Screenshot of room"

while True:

    camera.start_preview(alpha=200)    
    time.sleep(5)  
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')  
    camera.stop_preview()

    filename = "room.jpg"    
    attachment = open('../Desktop/image.jpg', "r")    
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')     
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)    
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg1.attach(part)
    text = msg1.as_string()
    myserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465)    
    myserver.login("jsmith05@yahoo.com.au", "Ch53644")    
    myserver.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 
    myserver.close()   

    time.sleep(120)
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you are sending the same message, with more content, over and over again. Move this :

```
msg1 = MIMEMultipart()
msg1['From'] = fromaddr
msg1['To'] = toaddr
msg1['Subject'] = "Screenshot of room"
```

In your `while` block and you should be fine

Comment: Dear Anthony, The program works now. Many thanks.  Qi

Comment: The while loop had worked for 3 iterations, and then stoped. The error message is: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (451, '4.3.2 Internal server error (##0CF014)'). The Pi is wirelessly connected to a router at home. What is the cause?

Comment: This looks like a server side issue to me, I don't see anything in your code that could cause such error. You could however surround the part of your code containing `myserver`s in a try/except block as not to crash when such an error is encountered

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. I will use try/except structure. Using that structure, will the while loop keep trying and continue?

Comment: Yes, it will, but the try except block needs to be inside the while, else it will not work